# React cannot read property map of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

I am very new to react and I am trying to bring in data from a rails api but I am getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

If i use the react dev tools I can see the state and I can see the contacts if I mess around with it in the console using `$r.state.contacts` Can someone help with what I have done wrong? my component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Contact from './Contact';

class ContactsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('http://localhost:3000/contacts')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          contacts: response.contacts
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
      })
  }

  render(){
    return(
     <ul>
        {this.state.contacts.map(contact => { return <Contact contact{contact} />})}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default ContactsList;
```

Comment: Did you verify that `response.contacts` is an array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line 0: Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62079477/line-0-parsing-error-cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, Why?

Because `this.state` is initially `{}`, and `contacts` of `{}` will be **undefined**. Important point is, **[componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)** will get called after initial rendering and it is throwing that error during first rendering.

**Possible Solutions:**

1- Either define the initial value of `contacts` as `[]` in state:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
    this.state = {
       contacts: []
    }
}
```

2- Or put the check before using `map` on it:

```
{this.state.contacts && this.state.contacts.map(....)
```

For checking array, you can also use `Array.isArray(this.state.contacts)`.

**Note:** You need to assign unique key to each element inside map, check the **[DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)**.

Comment: Doh! thanks works like a charm now, I will mark this as the answer when the 12mins are up.